# How do I calculate 16-bit checksum of a 5-byte data?

Tags: checksum

How do I calculate 16-bit checksum from a 5-byte data?
For example:

```
Byte number:  1    2    3    4    5
Value:        12   00   01   00   A0
```

I converted all the value to their binary format and tried to do the calculation but I'm not sure if my answer is correct.

```
12 = 0001 0010
00 = 0000 0000
01 = 0000 0001
00 = 0000 0000
A0 = 1010 0000
```

Calculation:

```
0001 0010 0000 0000
0000 0001 0000 0000
1010 0000 0000 0000
-------------------
1011 0011 0000 0000 (sum)
0100 1100 1111 1111 (checksum)
 4    C    F    F
```

Is my answer correct? I'm not sure about the third line in my calculation since the data is 5 bytes only.

Edit: I'm trying to do Internet Checksum (those for TCP/UDP segment).

Comment: There are many kinds of checksum. What kind is this?

Comment: What is the name of the algorithms you are using?

Comment: I'm trying to do [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Checksum_computation) kind of checksum.

Comment: Is [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) of help?

Comment: @Bart I tried that calculation but I'm not sure if my third calculation line is correct because the data is 5-bytes only. Can I add 8 0s to make it become 16-bit to calculate?

Comment: @VinhQuangTran There's a worked example at [Compute 16-bit One's Complement Sum](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/54379.html). Also, [As it turns out, all of the protocol layers in the TCP/IP suite are defined to be big endian.](https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/Big-Endian-Little-Endian)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I can do checksum with even number of bytes but I'm a bit confused whether I can do the same with odd number of bytes like in the example.

Comment: @VinhQuangTran By searching for "tcp checksum odd length" I found [The TCP/IP Checksum](https://locklessinc.com/articles/tcp_checksum/).

Comment: @AndrewMorton So it seems like my padding is correct. But what about 'While computing the checksum, the checksum field itself is replaced with zeros'?